# Создание фильтра для карточки посредством html, js, css, svg

Tags: javascript, html, css

Друзья, возник такой вопрос, как реализовать такой blur для карточки? Как переместить в низ карточки вопросов не возникает, а вот как сделать такой blur непонятно, кто-то может помочь в этом вопросе? Реализовать бы посредством js, html, css, svg или любыми другими методами[image: Пример блюра]

Comment: Надо жить и программировать по средствам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант(исправлено, используя пример некоего Stas'а https://codepen.io/html_man/pen/oeNvOa):

```css
*,*:after,*:before {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 outline: 0;
}
/*стили выше добавлены только для этого примера, в реальном проекте используйте normilize.css\reset.css*/
.main {
 position: relative;
 z-index: -1;
 height: 300px;
 width: 400px;
 border: 2px solid #000;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: url(https://www.visitfinland.com/app/uploads/Aland_Islands_fishing-400x300.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.filter-child {
 position: absolute;
 left: -10px;
 right: -10px;
 bottom: -10px;
 height: 110px;
 background: inherit;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: bottom;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.filter-child::after {
 content: '';
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 99;
 background: inherit;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.4);
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.4);
 -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
 filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="filter-child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Заюзайте что-то вреде этого: https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/633782900077408256/F541mrSs.jpg Однородный фон не так выразителен в размытии.

Comment: К сожалению данный пример не подходит, так как я его уже применял, но все равно спасибо вам за один из методов

Comment: @Aid, поправил.

Comment: @Лебедев Артем, а чем именно не подходит, что не так? И кстати не за что - я ж не помог ничем.

Comment: Да нет, я немного по другому сделал, если не придумаю как сделать, то сделаю вашим способом ( я не догадался что можно сделать длину 100% можно поставить, и выглядело не очень, а вы считай помогли :з )
А не подходит тем, что блюр эффект немного не тот, там же на картинки немного по другому выглядит

Comment: Да есть такое, надо подумать..

Comment: @ЛебедевАртем, поправил ответ, посмотрите.